# How to create a SQL table based on the attributes another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL table called SCUBA_DIVER. It contains the attributes ID (diver certification number), CDATE (certification date), and NAME.

I need to create a new table based on this one with two columns, ID1 and ID2. For each row the ID1 diver will always have been certified later than the ID2 diver. How would you set up this table? I'd like to get all combinations for each diver.

So far I have:

```
SELECT SCUBA_DIVER.ID AS ID1, SCUBA_DIVER.ID AS ID2
FROM SCUBA_DIVER AS SD1, SCUBA_DIVER AS SD2
WHERE SD1.CDATE > SD2.CDATE;
```

But this is giving me an error in Oracle and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Remove AS keyword in FROM clause and use aliases instead of table names.
You can create new table using CREATE TABLE AS SELECT statement:

```
CREATE TABLE <table name> AS
SELECT SD1.ID AS ID1, SD2.ID AS ID2
FROM SCUBA_DIVER SD1, SCUBA_DIVER SD2
WHERE SD1.CDATE > SD2.CDATE;
```